# Distrubuted PyTorch code halts on multiple nodes when using MPI backend

Tags: ssh, distributed, pytorch, openmpi, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to run Pytorch code on three nodes using openMPI but the code just halts without any errors or output. Eventually my purpose is to distribute a Pytorch graph on these nodes.

Three of my nodes are connected in same LAN and have SSH access to each other without password and have similar specifications:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Cuda 10.0
- OpenMPI built and installed from source
- PyTorch built and installed from source

The code shown below works on single node - multiple processes, as:

```
> mpirun -np 3 -H 192.168.100.101:3 python3 run.py
```

With following output:

```
INIT 0 of 3 Init env://
INIT 1 of 3 Init env://
INIT 2 of 3 Init env://
RUN 0 of 3 with tensor([0., 0., 0.])
RUN 1 of 3 with tensor([0., 0., 0.])
RUN 2 of 3 with tensor([0., 0., 0.])
Rank  1  has data  tensor(1.)
Rank  0  has data  tensor(1.)
Rank  2  has data  tensor(1.)
```

But when I placed the code on three nodes and run following command on each node separately, it does nothing:

```
> mpirun -np 3 -H 192.168.100.101:1,192.168.100.102:1,192.168.100.103:1 python3 run.py
```

Please give some idea about any modifications in code or configurations for MPI to run given Pytorch code on multiple nodes?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import torch
import torch.distributed as dist
from torch.multiprocessing import Process

def run(rank, size):
    tensor = torch.zeros(size)
    print(f"RUN {rank} of {size} with {tensor}")

    # incrementing the old tensor
    tensor += 1

    # sending tensor to next rank
    if rank == size-1:
       dist.send(tensor=tensor, dst=0)
    else:
       dist.send(tensor=tensor, dst=rank+1)

    # receiving tensor from previous rank
    if rank == 0:
        dist.recv(tensor=tensor, src=size-1)
    else:
        dist.recv(tensor=tensor, src=rank-1)

    print('Rank ', rank, ' has data ', tensor[0])


def init_processes(rank, size, fn, backend, init):
    print(f"INIT {rank} of {size} Init {init}")
    dist.init_process_group(backend, init, rank=rank, world_size=size)
    fn(rank, size)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = '192.168.100.101'
    os.environ['BACKEND'] = 'mpi'
    os.environ['INIT_METHOD'] = 'env://'
    world_size = int(os.environ['OMPI_COMM_WORLD_SIZE'])
    world_rank = int(os.environ['OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK'])

    init_processes(world_rank, world_size, run, os.environ['BACKEND'], os.environ['INIT_METHOD'])
```

N.B. NCCL is not an option for me due to arm64-based hardware.

Comment: What if you `mpirun -np 3 -H 192.168.100.101:1,192.168.100.102:1,192.168.100.103:1 hostname` ?

Comment: Thanks Gilles, as suggested I tried on alll three nodes `>> mpirun -np 3 -H 192.168.100.101:1,192.168.100.102:1,192.168.100.103:1 hostname python3 run.py`. but no luck. (Did I get you right? as I replaced `hostname` on each node with its own IP address, e.g. 192.168.100.101,  192.168.100.102,  192.168.100.103)

Comment: Try my exact command, this is a very basic Open MPI test that should print the three hostnames of your machines. At that stage, I do not know whether you are facing a `PyTorch` issue or a pure Open MPI one.

Comment: I am sorry Gilles, being new to openMPI i could not get at first. Now I have issued the exact command you said and here is the result: `ssh: connect to host 192.168.100.103 port 22: No route to host`
`ssh: connect to host 192.168.100.102 port 22: No route to host`. Whereas if I issue this `mpirun -np 3 -H 192.168.100.101:3 hostname` then it prints the public name of my PC over the network 3 times. Please suggest the solution to the problem in hand. Thanks

Comment: `mpirun` cannot ssh to the remote hosts. It could be a system (no `sshd` running), a firewall (port 22 blocked) or the hosts could simply be down. Unless you are using a Resource Manager, all hosts must be able to SSH each other and passwordless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for replying late to this, but I could solve the issue by adding **--mca** **btl_tcp_if_include** *eth1* flag to [`mpirun` command](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=tcp).

The reason for halt was that openMPI, by default, tries to locate and communicate with other nodes over local loopback network interface e.g. **lo**. We have to explicitly specify which interface(s) should be included (or excluded) to locate other other nodes.

I hope it would save someone's day :)